# How to isolate java module execution in a seperated thread/classloader?

Tags: java, module, isolation

In my webservice application I have to integrate a third party module to validate business rules, these modules are shipped with rather old libraries.

The old libraries are in conflict with my newer one.

Is there a way to isolate the third party module in a seperated thread/classloader within the running webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Technology/WhatIsOSGi).

Comment: For my needs OSGi feels like to break a butterfly on a wheel, isn't there a more easier way?

Comment: Java 8 will contain modularization, named [project jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/), I would have a look there too.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you will have to use it via reflection like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader (
    new URL [] {/* Classpath or isolated module here */},
    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader ().getParent ());

Class <?> isolatedModuleClass = classLoader.loadClass (
    /* Full name of class from isolated module */);

Object isolatedObject = 
    isolatedModuleClass.
        getConstructor (/* Constructor argument types */).
            newInstance (/* Constructor arguments */);

Object result =
    isolatedModuleClass.
        getMethod (/* Method name */, /* Method parameter types */).
            invoke (isolatedObject, /* Method arguments */);
```